# php native to codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with my native php. Can you give me tips? After I login how can I view details in database like name, email, gender, username through using codeigniter?

```html
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","enrollmentsystem");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
   
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM admin where  Username='$username'");
   
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class=" table-hover">
    <tr class="input-lg"><td>Username:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br></td><td class="text-info"><?php echo $row['Username'] ?></td></tr>
    <tr class="input-lg"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br></td><td class="text-info"><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></td></tr>
    <tr class="input-lg"><td>&nbsp;Password:<br></td><td class="text-info"><?php echo $row['Password'] ?></td></tr>
    <tr class="input-lg"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Email:<br></td><td class="text-info"><?php echo $row['Email'] ?></td></tr>
    <tr class="input-lg"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Gender:<br></td><td class="text-info"><?php echo $row['Gender'] ?></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
<?php
}
   
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Write query in model call query from controller pass query data in view and display it.. I think its nt easy its better to read CI manual its very simple

Comment: For yur help its very easy https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: still need session to perform?

Comment: Ofcourse if u r working on login than u need to store info in session

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html for session

Comment: I suggest u to try yur self than if u feel any issue than post as a question

Comment: it is ok i will  <?php $username ?> because i can access the session using this?

Comment: My friend yes u can store username in session and than u can access it anywhere the application

Comment: @FreezingBernUchiha Codeigniter has its on database.php file no need to use mysqli_connect on view http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few points before I begin:

1. CodeIgniter has a built in MySQL querying class. Your current implementation of querying is prone to MySQL injection. [Read more...](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/index.html)
2. Using the above query builder, you can get the results in many forms. [Read more...](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)
3. You should query the database in a model, and pass the data 
   to the view. [Read more about MVC here...](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html), and [read more about passing data to views here...](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)
4. You should definitely start with the tutorial [here](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html) which explains how to do something similar to what you want as well as other things to get you started.

However, if you wish to continue as it is, here are some things I noticed: 

In:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
```

`$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` does return a truthy value, but there is no code changing the query, so the server gets stuck in an infinite loop. 

Next, in:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM admin where  Username='$username'");
```

`$username` does not seem to be assigned. Im assuming it is assigned before the view is sent to the client?

Try fixing these and see if it works as you intend it to.